# Replace multiline string by multiline string using perl

Tags: regex, linux, perl, multiline

I'm trying to edit a tomcat configuration file using perl. I want to uncomment the following lines in an xml file. I tried it with perl, but it won't work.

```
<!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
-->
```

This is what i got:

```
perl -i -pe 's~<!--\n    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"\n              maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"\n              clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />\n    -->~<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"\n              maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"\n              clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />~' $CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml
```

Another question: can i find and replace a string with a regex?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please demonstrate that you are attempting to gain an understanding of the problem by providing an example if what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression is not the right tool to modify XML.
Use an XML aware library. For example, [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::LibXML;

my $xml     = 'XML::LibXML'->load_xml(location => 'file.xml');
my $comment = $xml->findnodes('//comment()')->[0];
my $inner   = 'XML::LibXML'->load_xml(string => $comment->textContent)
              ->getFirstChild;
$comment->replaceNode($inner);
print $xml;
```

Or shorter with the [xsh](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh)
 wrapper:

```
open file.xml ;
xinsert chunk string(//comment()[1]) replace //comment()[1] ;
save :b ;
```

Comment: Obligatory link to what happens when you try to use regex to parse XML or HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: While I agree generally, he did not actually ask for *parsing* the HTML, i.e. getting info out of it.

Comment: @Jan: The point is you can't reliably modify an XML document without parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

You could come up with:

```
~^(<!--.*\R)(\s+<Connector[^>]+>)(.*\R-->.*)~
```

And replace the match with the second group, see [a demo here on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/sW1dI3/2).